# How to re-write PHP code for WordPress WPML Language

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to change a specific line of PHP code within a WordPress plugin.

The default line of code is:

```
$post_content .= "<div class='artist_bio'>" . nl2br((string)$artist->bio_public) . "</div>";
```

The "bio_public" is pulling from a custom field. There is an additional custom field called "secondary_language_bio".

WPML documentation tells you how to target specific language codes. I need to write and if else statement similar to the code below but with the correct syntax:

```
$post_content .= "<div class='artist_bio'>" . if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE === "fr"){nl2br((string)$artist->secondary_language_bio)} else{nl2br((string)$artist->bio_public)} . "</div>";
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why not? `$post_content .= "<div class='artist_bio'>"; if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE === "fr"){$post_content .= nl2br((string)$artist->secondary_language_bio);} else{$post_content .= nl2br((string)$artist->bio_public);} $post_content .= "</div>";
`

Comment: Figured out why it wasn't working, the French version didn't copy the custom fields. Your code worked great, thanks a bunch!